# Where is the cat in Tacoma?

Tags: tacoma

I've finished Tacoma recently on PlayStation and one of the available achievements is the "Catsitter". I could find the cat on E.V's office, medical and cryogenics. Where else can I find that cat?

Comment: I once pet a cat in the city of Tacoma. Does that count?

Comment: @PausePause It counts if you can tell me where I can find it! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/tacoma/Housecat_Locations#Mechanical_Engineering), there is a total of 7 different emplacements where you can spot the cat.
There are two in the *personnel module*, two more in the *biomedical module*, another two in the *engineering module*, and the last one is in the *hub*.

Here's the precise location for each one (taken from linked guide, to avoid potential deadlink later) :

**Personnel Module**

> **Administration**
> [image: Cat location for Administration zone in Personnel Module]
> During the main Crew Recording in Administration, look into the
> Conference Room where E.V. St. James is pacing to find the housecat
> curled up on a chair in the corner.

> **Operations**
> [image: Cat location for Operations zone in Personnel Module]
> During the main Crew Recording in Operations, move into the Laundry
> Room and look up along the piping and vents to find the housecat
> asleep on top of some vents.

**Biomedical Module**

> **Botany**
> [image: Cat location for Botany zone in Biomedical Module]
> During the main Crew Recording in Botany, follow Sareh into Food
> Storage and look in the room on the left for vats of meat products,
> and in a hole in the grating above you can spot the housecat.

> **Medical**
> [image: Cat location for Medical zone in Biomedical Module]
> During the main Crew Recording in Medical, enter Sarah's medical exam
> area and head into the Imaging room, where you can find the housecat
> hiding under the main table.

**Engineering Module**

> **Mechanical Engineering**
> [image: Cat location for Mechanical Engineering zone in Engineering Module]
> During the main Crew Recording in Mechanical Engineering, head left
> from the main entrance into the Power Cell Room, and look up in the
> left corner above the cells to find the house cat asleep on top of
> some power cells.

> **Network Technology**
> [image: Cat location for Network Technology zone in Engineering Module]
> Once you spot the first of Sareh' AR Crew Recordings, turn around from
> Sareh and look up towards the windowsills at the top of the main area
> with the stairs to find the housecat asleep near the windowsill at the
> highest point - opposite the newly opened door.

**The Hub**

> There is one sighting of the housecat in The Hub, **only available at
> the end of the game**.
>
> > [image: Cat location in the hub]
> >  Once you've left the Engineering Module with ODIN's AI Wetware in
> >  hand, you'll view on last main AR Crew Recording. You can find the
> >  housecat safely in E.V.'s arms as they prepare to leave.